# Can't find a font with this slanted 'A'?

Tags: font-identification

I'm trying to match this font to recreate a business card, but I can't find it anywhere. I've tried font matching it on a range of websites but it comes out suggesting nothing or the wrong font. Does anyone know which it is?

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Font name :- **Dolce Vita** from http://muraknockout.com/dolce-vita/

**by MuraKnockout Media + Design**

[image]

Comment: Is it just me or does the space between the A & L look wider in this font than it does in the example by OP?

Comment: @Mast most likely the kerning was tweaked manually. See also the uneven spacing in "AIN".

Answer (score 9):

If you are just looking for the slanted A, the classical font with this design is [Avant Garde Gothic](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/avant-garde-gothic/) from myfonts.com,  designed by *[Herbert Lubalin](http://www.designishistory.com/1960/herb-lubalin/)* on the seventies. The original design brings optional glyphs like the slanted A or glyphs combinations.

[image: Avant Garde]

[image]

He designed after the same font but with serif, named [Lubalin Graph](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/lubalin-graph/) at myfonts.com

[image]

Comment: The "S" is different

Comment: Of course, the whole font is different, the subject was the slanted A

Comment: That's the subject not the question. Read the question "I'm trying to match a font to recreate..." - you can't exactly recreate the exact business card if the rest of the letters don't match

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding, I am talking about the subject of my answer, not the subject of the question. Do you think if I put at the beginning of the answer: – this is my appreciation about the subject that you mention in your question about the slanted character A –  will you be satisfied?

Comment: No. Because essentially this answer does not answer the question: how to replicate the font used in a business card

Comment: Read well the question please: recreate is different than replicate.

Comment: OK. But read the question please: matching the font is different than matching the letter A

Comment: In the future, please read the question, not just the title, before writing an answer.  While the information you present may be interesting, it does not address the issue at hand.  Thank you.

Comment: I will keep it in mind. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Coming from "Hot Network Questions", I really enjoy reading these slightly off-topic answers. My $0.02.

Comment: The second font demo says "faggiht" on the top line. Was this really necessary?

Comment: @MichaelFulton you’ll find that’s simply all the glyphs in alphabetical order. You might be reading too much into this

Comment: @EricDuminil You're not supposed to enjoy reading off-topic answers. They will punish you by taking away some of your brownie points. (Though if you come to StackOverflow for fun rather than for earning brownie points, there's actually nothing they can do about it...)